# Volley error response bytes does not convert from bytes to string

Tags: android, android-volley, android-webservice

```
CustomStringRequest customStringRequest = new CustomStringRequest(requestMethod.ordinal(), serverUrl,
            result -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "headers: " + result.headers);
                Log.d(TAG, "response: " + result.response);
                createTaskItem(result);
            },
            error -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "error: " + error);
            })
```

error is in `JSON` string, I tried to get error like this:

```
new String(error.networkResponse.data, "utf-8");
new String(error.networkResponse.data);
```

none of the above method works, i always get empty string, don't know why :(

[image]

as you can see bytes in picture, the error response is actually this:

```
   {
  "error": [
    "Wrong Credentials!"
  ],
  "email_exists": false
}
```

I am using:

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

Comment: have you added Response.ErrorListener in you request class ?

Comment: yeah! i got error successfully, `error -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "error: " + error);
            })`. The only thing is i can't convert it to string:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, i was just evaluating error response in debug mode 
`new String(error.networkResponse.data, "UTF-8");` 
and it returns empty string in result.
I just tried to print error response and it worked!. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your response to json object using **GSON** ,

```
 val customPojo = CustomPojo()

 val gson = Gson()
 gson.toJson(myPojo)
```

**CustomPojo** should be your response model class.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. how can i parse it to POJO without getting JSON string?